# How to solve $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{n \ln(n^3+5n)}{\ln(n^{3n} +n^7)}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use.
Can you show a method for the resolution with asymptotic approximations(so without Hopital)? Thanks

$$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{n \ln(n^3+5n)}{\ln(n^{3n} +n^7)}\right)$$

Comment: I think L'Hospital's would be the easiest method here, because of the way the ln's are constructed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3+5n)}{\ln(n^{3n} +n^7)}
=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln\left(n^3\left(1+\frac{5n}{n^3}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(n^{3n}\left(1+\frac{n^7}{n^{3n}}\right)\right)}
=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3)}{\ln(n^{3n})}
=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{3n\ln(n)}{3n\ln(n)}=1$$

---

More rigorous version for the bracket:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3+5n)}{\ln(n^{3n} +n^7)}
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln\left(n^3\left(1+\frac{5n}{n^3}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(n^{3n}\left(1+\frac{n^7}{n^{3n}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3)+n\ln\left(1+\frac{5n}{n^3}\right)}{\ln(n^{3n})+\ln\left(1+\frac{n^7}{n^{3n}}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3)+\frac5n\cdot\frac{n^3}{5n}\ln\left(1+\frac{5n}{n^3}\right)}{\ln(n^{3n})+\ln\left(1+\frac{n^7}{n^{3n}}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3)+\frac5n}{\ln(n^{3n})}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln(n^3)}{\ln(n^{3n})}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{3n\ln(n)}{3n\ln(n)}\\&=1
\end{align}

Comment: why the brackets inside the ln go away?

Comment: It went away because $\lim_{n\to\infty}5n/n^3=0$. Same thing for $n^7/n^{3n}$.

Comment: ah sure. thank you so much

Comment: @KayK. Not sure that argument is sufficient, or at least it may require a bit more detailing. For instance, $n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\to 1$, not $0$, although $\frac1n\to 0$: "the bracket does not always go away."

Comment: Yes, you need to write log(n^3(1+...)) as log(n^3)+log(1+...) and then bound the log(1+...) more carefully (it's not too hard but the argument as it stands is currently incomplete)

Comment: I added more detailed version but I frankly don't think it's necessary as $n\ln n + n\ln(1+\frac1n) \rightarrow \infty$ so the 2nd term doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

With *equivalents*, it is *very* short:
$$\frac{n\ln(n^3+5n)}{\ln(n^{3n}+n^7)}\sim_\infty\frac{n\ln n^3}{\ln n^{3n}}=\frac{n\cdot3\ln n}{3n\ln n}=1.$$